# Can someone explain js variable hoisting and stack execution for closures

Tags: javascript, closures, hoisting

While reading a different topic I came across this piece of code:

```
function loadme() {
 var arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
 var fs = [];
 for (var i in arr) {
   var x = arr[i];
   var f = function() { console.log(x) };
   f();
   fs.push(f);
 }
 for (var j in fs) {
   fs[j]();
 }
}
```

This will output: a,b,c,c,c,c. The problem here as explained by the author is that the x var is hoisted at the start of the function and therefore does not keeps it's value when it is used in the loop. What I do not understand is why is c assigned to x on the second console.log for 3 times? Can someone explain?

Comment: http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var x = arr[i];
var f = function() { console.log(x) };
```

In these two lines, `console.log(x)` thinks that it just has to print `x`. So, all the three functions are created that way only. So, when you immediately execute the functions, the value of `x` is different in each of the iterations. But when the looping is over, the variable `x` retains the last value it held and when the dynamically created functions are executed, they simply print the value of `x` which is `c`.

So, in order to fix this, you have to have your own copy of `x`, for each dynamically created function. Normally, we retain the current state of the variable which changes in the loop, with a function parameter, like this

```
var f = function(x) { return function() { console.log(x) } }(x);
```

Now, we are creating a function and executing it immediately, which returns another function and that returned function actually prints the value of `x`.

```
function(x) {
    return function() {
        console.log(x)
    }
}(x);
```

We are passing the value of `x` as a parameter to the wrapper function and now the current value of `x` is retained.

Comment: Downvoter, please let me know what is wrong with this answer.

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted because it's the right answer.

Comment: I hate it when they downvote and run away! This is a great answer.

Answer (score 4):

This situation is, in fact, quite easy to explain and it occurs in many programming languages, not just JavaScript.

Let's first take the output sequense `a,b,c,c,c,c` and discard the first three elements - `a,b,c` because this is what gets printed when you execute your function `f()` inside the first `for` loop.

So, we're left with the sequense `c,c,c` which gets printed when we iterate over the `fs` array. The reason why you don't get `a,b,c` printed is because the `x` parameter that you have inside your first `for` loop is *captured by reference* (not sure if the definition is valid, though) by your `f()` closure (remember, every function in JavaScript is a closure of some sort).

Now, since the `console.log(x)` expression is evaluated when you call the `f()`, the *current* value of the captured `x` parameter will be passed as an argument. While the code works, as seems to be expected, when you invoke `f()` inside the first `for` loop, the `x` is what has just been assigned from `arr[i]` so you get `a,b,c`. But when you exit the loop, the `x` (even though it's unavailable to the outer scope) is still captured by `f()` but after the first loop it has a value `c` (the one that it got on the last iteration) and that is what gets evaluated when you iterated over your functions the second time.

This is, in fact, can be a source of many confusing bugs and so some languages can detect this and notify the developer (for example, C# compiler, when it sees constructs like this, produces the following warning: `Access to modified closure`).

To fix the problem, you just need to capture *the current value* of `x` inside your first `for` loop:

```
for (var i in arr) {
    var x = arr[i];

    var f = (function(x) {
       return function() { console.log(x) };
    })(x);

    f();
    fs.push(f);
}
```

Here we use IIFE (Immediately-Invoked Function Expression) to capture the current value of `x`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yep thx, very clear and straightforward. cleared things in my head.